# Can't do XEN pci passthrough of onboard Intel HDA Sound Card (but works in KVM)

Tags: windows, xen, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to pass an onboard `SBx00 Azalia (Itel HDA)` through to a XEN windows guest, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The device appears in the device manager as `High Definition Audio Controller`, but under `System devices`, not `Sound, Video and Game Controllers` as I would expect, and under `Manage Audio Devices` windows claims there are no audio devices.

The weird thing is that when I try the same thing with KVM, windows detects it fine and can play sound.

Can anyone think of any reason why this would be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using `pci-stub` rather than `pciback`, oddly passing through other devices to xen guest went fine with pci-stub, but not this sound card. odd.